# Is there a way of replacing a string param in a rest path in Kotlin?

Tags: rest, kotlin

I want to write integration tests and thus call my endpoint "/cool/123".

The path is declared in the resource class in its companion object, `const val COOL_PATH = "/cool/{id}"`.
I imported it in my test, but in order to use this call I want to replace {id} by 123.

```
.get(CoolResourceCompanion.BASE_PATH + CoolResourceCompanion.COOL_PATH)
```

I guess I could parse it and replace it with string manipulations, but is there a more kotlin way to do so ?

Comment: Do you use some kind of a framework for REST API usage?